# Deploy Static View Files Explanation

Tags: magento2

can you please anyone  explain [This Documentation Topic](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html) briefly.

You can find the above link and explain me , some of the information i am not clear of it.

especially the command options,

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [<languages>] [-t|--theme[="<theme>"]] 
[--exclude-theme[="<theme>"]] [-l|--language[="<language>"]] 
[--exclude-language[="<language>"]] 
[-a|--area[="<area>"]] [--exclude-area[="<area>"]] [-j|--jobs[="<number>"]]
[--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images]
[--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [-f|--force]
```

like this.

Where we have to use?

if it is `production` or `developer` mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` in case you want to deploy static content to a production site. For developer mode it is not needed as the files are generated on the fly. Also, please try to be more specific on your questions as the whole page is difficult to explain unless you have specific doubt or question.

Comment: Why this command?bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [<languages>] [-t|--theme[="<theme>"]] 
[--exclude-theme[="<theme>"]] [-l|--language[="<language>"]] 
[--exclude-language[="<language>"]] 
[-a|--area[="<area>"]] [--exclude-area[="<area>"]] [-j|--jobs[="<number>"]]
[--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images]
[--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [-f|--force]

Comment: If you are trying to understand what are the other square bracketed items then let me add a bit more on it. They are optional arguments and you can pass as needed. For example if you need to deploy static content for front end only then the command would be `bin/Magento setup:content:deploy -a frontend` . In case of developer mode or if you want to force deploy then you need to add one more option `-f` at the end of the command and so on. You can read detail of each arguments on devdocs